# How do I scrape this element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMKCM.png)

I want to scrape the string of title=

I don't know how to do it.

**URL:** https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivZpaYCxEKMmd6Bb44wJvnFRn3qBjm55UYqn0gicZ_1JhmTnv84KkKpzLAK35nU8uDqlWr9Kx2I6kTIeVf_1lNlHzPHdnhnLptL3lYjaU2q1gL4ZaKpdTtBvp3jhqqIiEXjsNtBNTN6TdjZ_1rRnzK1eGghX3jkQQiFESYQDwkZHPuXaN7vZ50J5ZZGazHJ8ds_13Hylm51grQwenq506Z1gpaXnHGlte_1ME_1Y0SFltK-FftywdeG_1xDPi4jGiO81ImgKdshrYd9YIpHxyj1fNKaEuOvsH2pZ264QnP3O8fS3V22HA87OgPCY4ubh0N-jJH40b19RAYez5tdPNR2HttPigfixkLcg

can someone help me please?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivZpaYCxEKMmd6Bb44wJvnFRn3qBjm55UYqn0gicZ_1JhmTnv84KkKpzLAK35nU8uDqlWr9Kx2I6kTIeVf_1lNlHzPHdnhnLptL3lYjaU2q1gL4ZaKpdTtBvp3jhqqIiEXjsNtBNTN6TdjZ_1rRnzK1eGghX3jkQQiFESYQDwkZHPuXaN7vZ50J5ZZGazHJ8ds_13Hylm51grQwenq506Z1gpaXnHGlte_1ME_1Y0SFltK-FftywdeG_1xDPi4jGiO81ImgKdshrYd9YIpHxyj1fNKaEuOvsH2pZ264QnP3O8fS3V22HA87OgPCY4ubh0N-jJH40b19RAYez5tdPNR2HttPigfixkLcg')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('g-img',class_="GMCzAd BA0A6c"):
    print(link.get('title'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `Selenium` as the content is loaded dynamically.

```
pip install selenium
apt-get update 
apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

Then you can get the `html` with `Selenium` and pass it to `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivZpaYCxEKMmd6Bb44wJvnFRn3qBjm55UYqn0gicZ_1JhmTnv84KkKpzLAK35nU8uDqlWr9Kx2I6kTIeVf_1lNlHzPHdnhnLptL3lYjaU2q1gL4ZaKpdTtBvp3jhqqIiEXjsNtBNTN6TdjZ_1rRnzK1eGghX3jkQQiFESYQDwkZHPuXaN7vZ50J5ZZGazHJ8ds_13Hylm51grQwenq506Z1gpaXnHGlte_1ME_1Y0SFltK-FftywdeG_1xDPi4jGiO81ImgKdshrYd9YIpHxyj1fNKaEuOvsH2pZ264QnP3O8fS3V22HA87OgPCY4ubh0N-jJH40b19RAYez5tdPNR2HttPigfixkLcg")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
all_images = [i['title'] for i in soup.find_all('img', attrs={'id': re.compile('^dimg')})] #get the title of all img tags that have an id that starts with dimg
```

Then `all_images[0]` will contain:

```
https://www.pngfind.com/mpng/TRxwbhw_cartoon-tadpole-hd-png-download/
```

PS. I don't know what your goal is, but there are probably [easier](https://pypi.org/project/google_images_download/) solutions